# "I will invite him to the meeting on a lower/lesser frequency/basis?"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

I would like to ask for help: I am organizing a meeting for X people on a weekly basis. Now, there are some less involved stakeholders that should be invited only once a month. It occurred to me that I am not sure how to say:

"Some will be invited on a lesser/lower frequency/basis" is certainly wrong but I cannot think of anything better.
I am not looking for another means to express that, I would like to find out what would be the proper adjective and noun to use in a sentence like this one.

Comment: You could say **less frequently** but it's much simpler and clearer to say some weekly and some monthly.

Comment: Commonly - *Some will be invited **less often**.*

Comment: Why not be specific? These stakeholders will only be invited to attend once a month.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say, on a **less frequent** basis. Or, on a merely limited number of occasions as opposed to the other folks.

Answer (score 0):

If the schedule for these others is not rigidly defined, then you could say that "some others will be invited to these meetings **intermittently**"